# unexpected result when call frontend action from console

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i'm trying to call a frontend action from console like

```
php yii cron/test
```

console action is like:

```
public function actionTest(){
yii::$app->controllerNamespace = "frontend\controllers";
   $test = Yii::$app->runAction('web-service/test', [
]);
echo $test;
}
```

frontend action is like:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
 if ($action->id == 'test') {
   $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
 }
 return parent::beforeAction($action);
}

function actionTest(){
 $x="hi ";
 echo $x;
 return $x;
}
```

in command prmpot i get result like this

```
hi 0  // i have really tested this codes
```

"hi" is because of echo in actionTest but i can't understand why printed $test in console is 0?

it seems "return $x" won't work and $x is not returned to console action.

if i move frontend action to somewhere like component (of course with changes like removing beforeaction() and calling component instead of runaction()), i get expected result "hi hi".

Comment: There is no good reason to develop something like this in the first place.

Comment: @user2831723 why? yii2 docs says: "console applications are mainly used to create background and maintenance tasks that need to be performed for a website." background code like cron job sometimes need  access to model. although i can write this model access in console action 
 too but i think this is not good idea when this codes are already  written in backend or frontend.

Comment: yeah, sure. Use models as much as you want but there is no good reason to have any sophisticated logics defined in frontend/backend controllers that would be accessed by cronjobs. MVC should be a faily easy concept to grasp in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yii2 Console, the `\Yii:$app::runAction()` doesn't return data from action.

The `runAction()` returns an exit code from Console Application, so you get the `0` which means normal:

> The result of the action. This can be either an exit code or Response object. Exit code 0 means normal, and other values mean abnormal. Exit code of null is treaded as 0 as well.
>
> [yii-console-application#runAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-console-application.html#runAction()-detail)

---

#### Return response object Demo

frontend action:

```
public function actionTest($value='')
{
    return (object)['title'=>'Empty Object'];
}
```

console action:

```
public function actionTest($message = 'hello world')
{
    yii::$app->controllerNamespace = "frontend\controllers";
    $test = Yii::$app->runAction('web-service/test');
    echo $test->title;
}
```

Comment: tnx. doc says it can be a Response Object. how?

Comment: @user677900 You can return an object from web/action to catch it in console/action, I will add the example code to my answer. Cheers.